# How to install Chromium on NetBSD?

Tags: software-installation, chrome, netbsd, pkgsrc

I installed NetBSD and Firefox browser successfully but cannot install Chromium:

```
tak# pkgin install chromium
calculating dependencies... done.
nothing to do.
tak#
```

How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

[As far as I can see](http://cdn.netbsd.org/pub/pkgsrc/current/pkgsrc/README-all.html), Chromium is not part of NetBSD's package collection.

There is [an ongoing project to port it](https://wiki.netbsd.org/projects/project/pkgsrc-chromium/) though.